# Is it safe to use a disk after a successful fsck?

Tags: filesystem, fsck

I had not used my venerable ThinkPad T400 for about 2 weeks. I booted normally but was told to run fsck manually because of errors.

I'm using 12.04 and the disk in question is ext4, a Samsung Evo 840, mounted `noatime,nodiratime,discard,commit=600,errors=remount-ro`

I ran fsck.ext4 on my / (mounted ro) and it fixed some errors:

- Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list
- Block bitmap differences
- Free inodes count wrong

fsck fixed these errors and the reports the partition to be OK.

Is it safe to use a disk after a successful fsck?

Comment: What do you mean "safe"? If there are no errors, why not use it?

Comment: Dunno, that's why I'm asking. I was trying to find good documentation but being a FS dummy I only (as expected) found stuff that (naturally) was either too superficial or too deep (for my very limited knowledge of FS anyway).

Comment: Would be nice to explain the flag for "close"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific errors you mention are common after a crash or power loss and result from files still being open at the time of the crash.  `e2fsck` easily fixes them and gets the filesystem back to a sane state.

Answer (score 3):

> fsck fixed these errors and the reports the partition to be OK.

Well, `man` says:

> fsck - check and repair a Linux filesystem ... In  actuality,  fsck  is  simply a front-end for the various filesystem
>          checkers (fsck.fstype) available under Linux.

So, if `fsck` reports that everything is all well and good, take it as so!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You're worse off running a Linux system without running fsck than running fsck. FSCK repairs your Linux. Here's one experience, if anyone wants to know:
My Ubuntu was acting strange. So many errors. I decided to go on recovery. It for some reason didn't even boot. It told me to run fsck, and that /dev/sda5 had errors. I did fsck /dev/sda5 and after some time, the computer had no errors. Remember: fsck is your friend.